# I can't get my drawed picture in browser

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML code:

```
<body >
<canvas id ="my_canvas" width =500 height =500></canvas>
</body >
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var canvas = document.getElememtById("my_canvas");
var c=canvas.getContext("2d");
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(100,200);
c.lineTo(200,200);
c.fill();
c.stroke();
c.endPath();
```

After all done,I can't see anything in browser.

Comment: Check your spelling `getElememtById` and do some basic debugging. Also, what's `endPath`?

Comment: remember many times javascript will yield absolutely nothing if there is something you don't need in it. I posted a working example I tested in fiddle below

Comment: @j08691 sorry,it is "closePath"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your syntactically right   code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(100,200);
c.lineTo(200,200);
c.closePath();
c.stroke();
c.fill();
```

```html
<body >
  <canvas id="my_canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body >
```

You had multiple syntax errors in your code.
It is closePath instead of endPath and your element's  spellings were wrong.I might have missed some in hurry .Just have a look on the syntax.

Comment: Thank you I'll check that out.

Comment: Check out now,the placement of code is also not right.You need to fill in the end.

Comment: thank you for you solution, I think I found what is wrong in my code, I put HTML code and JavaScript code at two single files,so I just add code "window.onload=(function(){/*put above code here*/ });  " in JavaScript file to wait HTML code complete load in browser .   And now it's work fine. I wondering it's that the only way to solution this that must be wait until browsers load whole HTML code and add above code in JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

working 
example
HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
```

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```